BasicHttpBinding HttpClientCredentialType.Basic with .NET MAUI and Android not working
I have a WCF service that I am trying to access via multiple platforms: Windows console app, .NET Maui iOS, .Net Maui Android.  I use BasicHttpBinding.  I need to pass credentials to the WCF service.
I can only get the MAUI Android client to work if I use ClientCredentialType = None which does not accept credentials.  Windows and MAUI iOS work with ClientCredentialType = Basic.  I need to pass credentials because the client apps have different behavior depending on the group membership of the authenticated user.
The message received when debugging from the .NET MAUI Android platform is:
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: 'The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm=""'.'
The Windows Console and .NET MAUI iOS platform work fine.
During development and testing I have the Android client using ClientCredentialType = None as this is the only mode I can get the app to work, but I am getting closer to deployment and I need credentials passed so I can set up the different group driven behaviors that work across all platforms.
In the WCF Server App I am currently using the endpoint definition below which uses ClientCredentialType = None and works on all three client platforms but does not accept credentials:
        Dim binding As New BasicHttpBinding
        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None
        selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(IWCF), binding, "WCFService")

I want to be using the endpoint definition below, but it only works on Windows Console and .NET MAUI iOS platforms and gives the error when run from Android.  Notice the only difference is the "HttpClientCredentialType.None"
        Dim binding As New BasicHttpBinding
        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic
        selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(IWCF), binding, "WCFService")

In the .NET MAUI app, the service reference that is auto-generated from the dotnet-svcutil utility when using the ClientCredentialtype = Basic is as follows:
    private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
    {
            System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
            result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
            result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.AllowCookies = true; 
            result.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
            result.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
            return result;

    }

In the client apps, when calling the WCF methods using CredentialType = Basic I un-comment the following lines.  They are commented out when using CredentialType = None
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "[username]"
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "[Password]"

There have been a few other similar questions posted in the past and several people have stated that they found a solution but NONE of them actually posted their solution.  Very frustrating!
If Android .NET MAUI requires a completely different authentication than BasicHttpBinding in order to pass credentials I am OK with that but I can't find any guidance on how to do this.

Is it a http request or a https request? Android doesn't support http request defaultly.

It is a http request.  When I use ClientCredentialType = None everything works fine so Android doesn't appear to mind http in this configuration.

Did you try to set the realm property such as result.Security.Transport.Realm="your value"?

I did not have the realm property set, so I set it on the server side and receive basically the same message:
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: 'The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="your value"'.'
This happens regardless if I set the realm property on the client side.

Did you test on Android emulator or physical device?
